# Why do I get this warning: '@Model.property' is not a valid value of attribute 'checked'?

Tags: asp.net-core, checkbox, warnings, compiler-warnings, razor-pages

I have several checkboxes that I use for display purposes of 'true' and 'false'. Each one will show me the above warning (I made the warning more generic for the purposes of searching. In reality, it reads @Model.Service_Request_Information.Servicelead, etc, instead of @Model.property)

`<input class="custom-control-input" type="checkbox" checked="@item.Servicelead" disabled />`

I have read that it is okay to write razor code like this, and the HTML will insert/leave out 'checked' from the attributes depending on the value. It works fantastically for how I want it, and it doesn't prevent my code from compiling. So, any ideas on why I am getting this warning?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Razor will render a boolean attribute if the expression you pass to it evaluates to `true`. If the expression evaluates to `false`, the attribute is not rendered at all. That is the Razor feature you are using in your example.

In HTML, valid values for the `checked` attribute are an empty string or "checked" ([Specs](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/common-microsyntaxes.html#boolean-attribute)) i.e. `checked` or `checked="checked"`. Visual Studio reports HTML errors as warnings by default, which is what you are seeing. You can either ignore it, turn HTML validation off:

Tools > Options > Text Editor > Html > Validation

Or you can use a ternary expression as demonstrated by other answers:

```
@(item.Servicelead? "checked" : "")
```

Comment: Thank you! My question was intended to be geared more towards understanding why I was getting the warning for them at all since it's Razor feature. I didn't know that VS was validating for HTML as well. Much appreciated!

Comment: @Mike Brind How does your answer differ from mine? Same solution, only posted 13 hours later?

Comment: @citronas Technically, your statement "The checked attribute does not have a value" is incorrect. The checked attribute can have a value according to the HTML specs. The reason you provided in your answer is not the cause of the warning that the OP asked about.

Answer (score 0):

The checked attribute does not have a value. It should only be set when `@item.Servicelead` is true.

Use this code instead:

```
<input class="custom-control-input" type="checkbox" @(item.Servicelead? "checked" : "") disabled />
```

Comment: Thank you for answering! There's a feature for Razor that renders the "checked" as an HTML attribute only if that Razor value is true. I was mostly wanting to understand why I was getting a warning at all since it is an available feature. Still, it was useful to know an expression I could use to make the warning disappear.